Unable to establish WebSocket connection through Google Cloud Application Load Balancer
I am trying to configure WebSocket connections for my application hosted on Google Cloud using a Global External Application Load Balancer, but I am facing issues. Here's my setup:
Setup:

I have a single VM instance running two services:

Authentication Service on port 8080, accessible via https://auth.forge-code.com.
Notification Service on port 8081, accessible via https://notify.forge-code.com.


The notification service exposes a WebSocket endpoint on /ws/* (e.g., wss://notify.forge-code.com/ws/546).

I am using a Global External Application Load Balancer with the following configuration:

Frontend:

Protocol: HTTPS
HTTP keepalive timeout: 1200 seconds
SSL certificates configured for both subdomains (auth.forge-code.com, notify.forge-code.com).


Routing Rules:

auth.forge-code.com routes all traffic to auth-backend.
notify.forge-code.com/ws/* routes traffic to notify-backend.
Other traffic to notify.forge-code.com routes to notify-backend.


Backends:

auth-backend:

Port: 8080
Timeout: 30 seconds


notify-backend:

Port: 8081
Timeout: 30 seconds
Cloud CDN: Enabled
Logging: Enabled (sample rate: 1).






DNS resolves auth.forge-code.com and notify.forge-code.com correctly to the load balancer's IP.


The Problem

HTTP requests to endpoints like https://notify.forge-code.com/health work perfectly.
WebSocket connections to wss://notify.forge-code.com/ws/546 fail with the following errors:

Postman: 502 Bad Gateway
Browser console (sometimes): socket hang up.


Direct WebSocket connections to the backend (ws://34.133.145.146:8081/ws/546) succeed.

Additional Information:

Backend service is implemented in Rust using ntex and logs indicate that WebSocket connections are dropped as soon as they are initiated via the load balancer.
I suspect the issue occurs when traffic returns from the backend to the load balancer, but I’m not sure how to debug this further.

Logs:
Here’s a snippet of the backend logs when the connection is dropped:
[INFO  ntex::web::middleware::logger] 35.191.206.16:41366 "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0" 0.000069
[INFO  notify_service::services::websocket_service] Client disconnected: 546
[INFO  notify_service::services::websocket_service] Connection dropped, stopping heartbeat task.

1. Postman connecting to wss://notify.forge-code.com/ws/546:

Error: 502 Bad Gateway
Handshake Details:

Request:
GET /ws/546 HTTP/1.1
Host: notify.forge-code.com
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x14nFpQQ/RYw17KRaAYteA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits


Response:
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Content-Length: 110
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close
Via: 1.1 google
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2024 10:50:58 GMT
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000






2. Direct Connection to Backend (ws://34.133.145.146:8081/ws/546):

Handshake Details:

Request:
GET /ws/546 HTTP/1.1
Host: 34.133.145.146:8081
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: HBB28rJBqzubIZpcjX4IFQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits


Response:
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: BMDxeu6H/GzSXaTDwL4/gunqy1A=
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2024 10:51:19 GMT






3. Postman connecting to ws://notify.forge-code.com/ws/546:

Error: socket hang up
Handshake Details:

Request:
GET /ws/546 HTTP/1.1
Host: notify.forge-code.com
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: KgravwbL2GoTBZkgHj1uFQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits


No Response.



Notes:

Edited to clarify that there is no 400 error.
Included logs and handshake details as requested.

Questions

Why are WebSocket connections failing through the load balancer, even though HTTP traffic and direct WebSocket connections to the backend work fine?
How can I resolve this issue so that WebSocket connections through the load balancer succeed?


Edit your post and include a log of the HTTP request made by the client including headers and the response from the load balancer. The Chrome debugger provides these details. The ALB provides default support for HTTP/HTTPS connects provided the clients sends a Connection: Upgrade header. The 400 error might indicate that you have a broken client or websocket implementation.

@JohnHanley I have edited the question. If there's anything i'm missing, please let me know

Have you verfied the route for notify.forge-code.com/ws/* is actually received by the backend? I am leaning towards a route or backend misconfiguration.
